# OPP PHP i cannot figure out what is wrong here

Tags: php, class, oop

This code does not return or output anything, i cant figure out what am i doing wrong in this case, please help me

```
 class Foo
 {
    protected $bar;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->bar = 1;
   }

   public static function doSomething()
   {
    return $this->bar;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually calling any function? ( I don't see it on your code) If so, start by by adding  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`  at the top of your php in order to debug it properly. What does it output?

Comment: "*This code does not return or output anything,*" no but your error logs will be. You really should spend some time reading them when you have a problem, they tell you what is going on in your code!

Comment: your snippet is not supposed to output anything, is it ? please upload a [MCVE]

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `$this` inside `static` method. You can remove `static` to make a method of `Foo` object.

```
class Foo
{
    protected $bar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = 1;
    }

    public function doSomething() // not static
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->doSomething();
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

If you want to use static members, you could do something like:

```
class Foo
{
    static protected $bar;

    static public function init()
    {
        self::$bar = 1;
    }

    static public function doSomething()
    {
        return self::$bar;
    }
}

Foo::init();
echo Foo::doSomething();
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

Or a bit of both:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    protected $bar;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = 1;
    }

    static public function doSomething()
    {
        return (new self())->bar;
    }
}

echo Foo::doSomething();
```

Outputs:

```
1
```

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone for the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49742778/revisions).

Comment: np, nice answer